# Find records with no association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

```
shipment has_one :invoice
invoice belongs_to :shipment
```

For every shipment, one invoice can be created. I want to find all the shipments that don't have an invoice yet. Preferably no direct SQL, I would like to use rails' find method.

Answer (score 3):

Do you consider altering your schema a little bit?

```
class Shipment
  belongs_to :invoice
end

class Invoice
  has_one :shipment
end
```

Then you'll be able to do this:

```
Shipment.where(:invoice_id => nil)
```

Explanation:

Both `has_one` and `belongs_to` express one-to-one relationship. And if it's a `belongs_to`, then model gets to store a foreign key to another record in the association. So, in this case, table `shipments` will contain `invoice_id`, which you'll be able to use.

Comment: well the Shipment is created first, then to create an Invoice, I select a dropdown menu with shipments to select what shipment the invoice is for. if i do it with the schema above, i would need to enter a value in the shipments table when recording a new row in the invoices table.

Comment: @leonel: is there a `NOT NULL` constraint? Can't you assign `invoice_id` later?

Comment: I tried your solution but I had to add a before_save to add the invoice_id, and then a after_destroy to delete the invoice_id if the invoice is deleted, it seemed like it was more error prone. So I was thinking about doing something like Shipment.all Invoice.all and then find the difference between the two.

Comment: @leonel: that's an option too :-)